# Adding unexisting sections to TOC with numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm writing some notes for a course and I need to present an outline of them. I want to use the same file with which I am working to do this, so I added phantom sections via hyperref to the TOC. The result is good, but I'd like these phantom chapters to have their appropriate numbers. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\input{intro}

\input{chap1}

\phantomsection{\label{chap2}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title for chap. 2}

\phantomsection{\label{chap3}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title for chap. 3}

\phantomsection{\label{chap4}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title for chap. 4}

\end{document}
```

I already have some text on both the Intro and Chap. 1. What I want is to these yet unexisting chapters have their number. Here's the output: [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks super complicated. Why not `\chapter{Title for chap. 2}`???

Comment: Because that generates more pages, and I don't want to have more of those than I currently need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the number for each chapter added to the TOC with `\addcontentsline` by using the `\numberline` command. For example, the TOC
[image]
is produced by the following example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{Title for chap. 1}
\section{Some section here}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\label{chap2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}{Title for chap. 2}}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\label{chap3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}{Title for chap. 3}}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\label{chap4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{\thechapter}{Title for chap. 4}}

\end{document}
```